# How to Redirect to new Html Page After Record Inserted to Mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I have inserted values from html to mysql database using Php.Records are stored in the database successfully but after getting the message from server it should redirect to new html page.
 I have tried using windows.location.href to go to next page but it didn't works.

```
<form id="studentdata" action="http://nidhinkumar06-001-site1.1tempurl.com/PrakashPHP/insave.php" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" id="schoolnam" name="School_Nam">
        <input type="hidden" id="grad" name="Gradez">
        <input type="hidden" id="stuname" name="Student_Nam">
        <input type="hidden" id="subj" name="Subz">
        <input type="hidden" id="date" name="Datez">
        <input type="hidden" id="imgtag" name="ImgTag">
        <input type="hidden" id="stuno" name="StudentNo">
        <input type="hidden" id="szhoolno" name="SchoolNo">
        <span id="dt"></span>
    <h6>Student_No:</h6> <h5 id="Student_No"></h3>

    <h6>Student_Name:</h6> <h5 id="Student_Name"> </h2>
   <h6>Grade</h6><p id="Grade"></p>
    <h6>School_Name:</h6><p id="School_Name"></p>
    <span id="subcz"></span>    
<select id="select">
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="Maths">Maths</option>
<option value="Science">Science</option>
</select> 
<h6>imageTag:</h6><p id="imagetag"></p>
<h6>SchoolNo:</h6><p id="schoolno"></p>
```

Capture

```
function ins(){
      var School_N=$('#School_Name').text();
      var grad_N=$('#Grade').text();
      var Student_N=$('#Student_Name').text();
      var Subj_N=$('#subcz').text();
      var Date_N=$('#dt').text();
      var Imagetag_N=$('#imagetag').text();
      var Stu_N=$('#Student_No').text();
      var Schol_N=$('#schoolno').text();
      document.getElementById("schoolnam").value=String(School_N);
      document.getElementById("grad").value=String(grad_N);
      document.getElementById("stuname").value=String(Student_N);
      document.getElementById("subj").value=String(Subj_N);
      document.getElementById("date").value=String(Date_N);
      document.getElementById("imgtag").value=String(Imagetag_N);
      document.getElementById("stuno").value=String(Stu_N);
      document.getElementById("szhoolno").value=String(Schol_N);
      //alert(String(Student_N));        
     window.location="camera.html";
```

}

Comment: in php you can redirect using `header('Location: <URL>');`

Comment: but how can i redirect to a client path in php even i have tried it

Comment: are you using ajax post to submit the form?

Comment: no i didn't use ajax post to submit the form

Comment: That should be `window.location.href="camera.html"` (some browsers accept it without the `href` part, too – but that is wrong, because if it was taken literally it would overwrite the whole location object.)

Comment: even i tried window.location.href="camera.html" but it didn't works

Answer (score 0):

Use the `header('Location: xxx.php)` in PHP to send a header to the browser to tell it to go and get another page.

Remember to use a `exit;` after though like this as `header()` does not stop the execution of the script, it just throws a header at the browser :-

```
// update completed OK

header('Location: new.php');
exit;
```

Comment: but how can i redirect to a client path in php even i have tried it

Answer (score 0):

if your window.location method isn't working then your code is probably breaking at some point higher up the list.

Perhaps inside your function, comment in some alerts. For each one that fires, you will know that everything above it executed properly.

E.g.-

```
function ins(){

    alert('function ins is running');

      var School_N=$('#School_Name').text();
      var grad_N=$('#Grade').text();
      var Student_N=$('#Student_Name').text();
      var Subj_N=$('#subcz').text();
      var Date_N=$('#dt').text();
      var Imagetag_N=$('#imagetag').text();
      var Stu_N=$('#Student_No').text();
      var Schol_N=$('#schoolno').text();

    alert('variables have all been set');

      document.getElementById("schoolnam").value=String(School_N);
      document.getElementById("grad").value=String(grad_N);
      document.getElementById("stuname").value=String(Student_N);
      document.getElementById("subj").value=String(Subj_N);
      document.getElementById("date").value=String(Date_N);
      document.getElementById("imgtag").value=String(Imagetag_N);
      document.getElementById("stuno").value=String(Stu_N);
      document.getElementById("szhoolno").value=String(Schol_N);

    alert('if this runs then everything above is okay');

     window.location="camera.html";
}
```

To me it looks like your value=String might be the issue (because your window.location looks fine.)

Have you tried changing your variables to a string in the first section?

E.G. instead of:

```
var School_N=$('#School_Name').text();
```

you could try:

```
var School_N=$('#School_Name').text().toString();
```

then in your second half of the function you're just setting the value to the direct variable rather than trying to parse it to a string at the same time as setting the elements value to it. I've never actually seen the JS code String(variable).. I've always known it to be variable.toString(); - but I could be wrong.

Good Luck! :-)

Comment: I can able to insert the values to mysql database successfully but after the echo statement it shows a white screen not going to camera.html page

Comment: do all three alerts in my example come up? That's a strong indicator that every line of code is working. That function you posted doesn't have any mySQL connectors so my best guess is you are inserting into mySQL seperately.

When the screen goes white, what does the address bar say at the top of the page? Is it possible that you mean to link to camera.php? you may simply have a blank camera.html file. Might seem trivial but worth checking :-)

Comment: No camera.html opens the camera and it is not empty